# WebView cookies not working

Tags: java, android, cookies, webview

Before saying this is a duplicate, none of the solutions around stackoverflow worked for me.
I have an app which has a button.
Once the button is clicked, a webviewActivity with a webview is opened.
It has a login, and when I type my login and try to access the rest of the website (with my credentials already on) I cant due to not been logged in.

Here is my WebViewActivity

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private static byte[] finaldata;
    FileInputStream finall = null;
    private static boolean loopSleep = false;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);    

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
        ws.setSaveFormData(false);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        String dbPath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
        webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(dbPath);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        setContentView(webView);
        webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.33:8080/formsvi/login.html");

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains("TAKEPICWITHCAMERA")) 
            {
                //OPEN CAMERA AND TAKE PICTURE              
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
                }
                while (!loopSleep)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }        
                }  
                loopSleep = false;
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(finaldata);
                return new WebResourceResponse("text/html", "UTF-8", is);    
             }          
            else
            {
                return null;
            }               
        }
    }

    }
```

Hope the camera code or the `shouldInterceptRequest` I have has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: That loop will never exit, it is also keeping the device busy wasting battery.

Comment: just until the picture is taken, that is not the issue.
That is just a temporal fix because if the activity continues, the picture is not sent with the intent

Comment: At the very least you need to look into AsyncTasks (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: What about the cookies

Comment: What about the webpage? Show us the code where you set and read the cookies or we can't find the issue. A WebView is a really bad way to make use of device though, I can't see why you aren't doing this natively

Comment: Is an enterprise website I cant give you, but it works under normal browsers on desktops, laptops, phones, tablets...but not under my app which contains this webView.

Comment: thanks for the tip @OGHaza, I just edit everything that I see is not correct or can be changed or looks better if formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was my problem:

```
    String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
```

I was forgetting to set the application cache path!